# Adding Vertical Navigation to PageLayout

Tags: navigation, page-layout

Is it possible to add Vertical Navigation to a "Page Layout", The reason is I want to make the navigation be visible only on some of the pages (same Master Page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the 'Current Navigation'/'Quicklaunch'?

If so, it should be a simple matter of stripping the Quicklanch nav code out of the masterpage and inserting it in the appropriate place in your page layout.

Comment: What about you have not access to the master page

Comment: In the page layouts where you want it hidden, embed some CSS (`display: none;`) that will hide the container of the Quicklaunch.